# Distributed consensus matrix form — is this form correct?

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

$$\dot \xi = - (L_{n} \otimes I_{m}) \xi$$

This equation is commonly cited in works about the distributed consensus of cooperative control, in fact, it's the matrix form of the basic consensus algorithm

I just got confused with dimensions of matrices, It's already given that $\epsilon$ is $n \times m$, so is $\dot \epsilon $, but what is confusing is that the Kronecker product gives an $n m \times n m$, so normally we can't have a matrix product between $n m \times n m$ matrix and an $n \times m$ one, dimensions don't match! Can one clarify this for me, please

Comment: it's supposed to show the Kronecker product symbol, I couldn't fix that !!

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: refresh your page, I change it to $ \xi $. regardless of the name of it's a matrix with dimensions: $ \n x m$, it represents the dynamics of n vehicles of the system, say n vehicles modeled with a $ \m $ order model each

Comment: If you don't want to define all symbols, just cite the paper and post a print-screen.

Comment: my question is just about the dimensions matches, I can understand the theory behind the equation when written in differential equations form, but using the Kronecker product to give a matrix form still confusing for me as I explained in the question the Kronecker product is supposed to give an n*m by n*m matrix, however $ \xi $ matrix is n by m one, so the matrix product is done?